# Combine two dataframe having one to many relationship

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge, one-to-many

I want to combine two dataframe like below but not getting what func to use for this.  i tried to breakdown problem but not getting correct solun -

```
import pandas as pd


person_data = [{'Id': 3763058, 'Name': 'Andi', 'description': 'abc'},
               {'Id': 3763077, 'Name': 'Mark', 'description': 'xyz'}]

person_df1 = pd.DataFrame(person_data)
display(person_df1)
```

| Id | Name | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3763058 | Andi | abc |
| 3763077 | Mark | xyz |

```
object_data = [{'Id': 3763058, 'object_name': 'PlayStation', 'object_count': 2},
               {'Id': 3763077, 'object_name': 'MathsBook',   'object_count': 1},
               {'Id': 3763058, 'object_name': 'MusicSystem', 'object_count': 3},
              ]

object_df2 = pd.DataFrame(object_data)
display(object_df2)
```

| Id | object_name | object_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3763058 | PlayStation | 2 |
| 3763077 | MathsBook | 1 |
| 3763058 | MusicSystem | 3 |

Result DF -

| Id | Name | description | PlayStation | MathsBook | MusicSystem |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3763058 | Andi | abc | 2 | 0 | 3 |
| 3763077 | Mark | xyz | 0 | 1 | 0 |

I tried to breakdown prob -

> part-1 : get unique values of object_name

```
# uniqe_object_name = object_df2['object_name'].unique().tolist()

new_cols= ['PlayStation', 'MathsBook', 'MusicSystem'] # As of now fix value we have
new_vals = [0,0,0]
```

> part-2 : Create column of unique object_name and initiate with zero

```
person_df1 = person_df1.reindex(columns=person_df1.columns.tolist() + new_cols)
person_df1[new_cols] = new_vals
print(person_df1)
```

> part3 : Group by id and store values of object_count to  object_name column
> Stuck here , not getting what func to use to create a column from other df and assign value from other df columns.

```
person_df1['id'][object_name] = object_df2.groupby('id')['object_name'].apply(', '.join).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First apply [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), then [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
out = person_df1.merge(object_df2.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='object_name',
                                              values='object_count', fill_value=0
                                             ).reset_index())
```

Or, to be explicit on the key and type of merge:

```
out = person_df1.merge(object_df2.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='object_name',
                                              values='object_count', fill_value=0
                                             ),
                      left_on='Id', right_index=True, how='left'
                      )
```

Output:

```
        Id  Name description  MathsBook  MusicSystem  PlayStation
0  3763058  Andi         abc          0            3            2
1  3763077  Mark         xyz          1            0            0
```

If the order of objects is important:

```
out = person_df1.merge(object_df2.pivot_table(index='Id', columns='object_name',
                                              values='object_count', fill_value=0
                                             )[object_df2['object_name'].unique()],
                      left_on='Id', right_index=True, how='left'
                      )
```

Output:

```
        Id  Name description  PlayStation  MathsBook  MusicSystem
0  3763058  Andi         abc            2          0            3
1  3763077  Mark         xyz            0          1            0
```